# Favicon Icon-MVC3 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is the need of favicon.ico. I am trying to use MVC error handling and it complaines file being missed.How do get rid off this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to the `RegisterRoutes` method of the **Global.asax.cs** file, and add this, as one of the first lines:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: I have done this and restared the Webserver but still happens same issue.

Comment: sorry Martin, I have restared the VS and it got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use it, instead of getting rid of it. Cause it's part of the web standards in UI design. Don't you like branding of your site? Then this is a crucial part of that branding.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

`<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.youraddress.com/youricon.ico"/>"` if you use localhost then  href="http://localhost:port/youricon.ico"
Note:Use other name instead favicon.ico.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the beginning of your RegisterRoutes method:

routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

Your browser will always ask the site for the favicon, this will ensure mvc doesn't try to resolve it.